# In Ruby, is there a way to accomplish what `with` does in Actionscript?

Tags: ruby, actionscript

In Ruby, I would like to select a default object for a block.

An example in Actionscript is:

```
with (board) { 
    length = 66; 
    width = 19; 
    fin_system = 'lockbox'; 
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
board.length = 66;
board.width = 19;
board.fin_system = 'lockbox';
```

Here is the documentation for this statement in Actionscript:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/statements.html#with

How can I accomplish this in Ruby?

Comment: WHY do you want to use with? Other than _eval_, _with_ is the worst part of ECMAScript (a.k.a. javascript and actionscript)

Comment: @invisible bob, why do you think `with` is bad? Just for interest

Comment: @invisible bob, easiest/quickest answer is to follow DRY principles.  Repetitively typing `board.` is not DRY.

Comment: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Hash.new.tap do |h|
  h[:name] = "Mike"
  h[:language] = "Ruby"
end
#=> {:name=>"Mike", :language=>"Ruby"}
```

You could try [Object#tap](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/Object.html#M000191) with Ruby 1.9.

So in your case:

```
board.tap do |b|
  b.length = 66;
  b.width = 19;
  b.fin_system = "lockbox"
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't seen `tap()` before.  I'd still like to save those two keystrokes (`b.`).  I was thinking of creating a `with(obj, hash)` function that would allow for `with board, { :length => 66, :width => 19, :fin_system => 'lockbox' }`, but this just moves the keystrokes to `:`, `>`, and `,`.

Answer (score 3):

One way to implement it is with `instance_eval`, like that:

```
def with(obj, &blk)
  obj.instance_eval(&blk)
end

a = "abc"
with a do
  self << 'b'
  gsub!('b', 'd')
  upcase!
end
puts a #=> ADCD

with board do 
  self.length = 66
  self.width = 19
  self.fin_system = 'lockbox'
end
```

But in some cases you have to use `self` (with operators and setting methods).

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution.  But I think using Ruby's native `tap`, as @MikeLewis described, is more elegant, saves keystrokes, and... is native.

Answer (score 1):

You can't accomplish that exactly in Ruby because `foo = bar` will always set a `foo` local variable; it will never call a `foo=` method. You can use tap as suggested.

One solution to the larger design question would be to use a fluent interface:

```
board.length(66).width(20)

class Board
  def length(amt)
    @length = amt
    self
  end

  def width(amt)
    @width = amt
    self
  end
end
```

It's up to you to decide if this pattern suits your use case.