# Assign class variables in a do block with ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm having a problem in ruby and I can't seem to find the solution even though I know it's somehow possible. I have a class and I want to assign some variables to it in a do block like so:

```
tester = Person.new
tester do
    :name => 'Andy'
    :example => 'Example'
end

puts "#{tester.name}:#{tester.example}" #Should output 'Andy:Example'
```

Has anyone got any ideas? I apologise for my terrible way of explaining. I'm new to Ruby :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the good old `yield self` idiom for that too:

```
class Person 
  attr_accessor :name, :example

  def initialize 
    yield self if block_given?
  end
end

tester = Person.new do |p|
  p.name = 'Andy'
  p.example = 'Example'
end

puts "#{tester.name}:#{tester.example}"
```

Comment: +1. `yield self if block_given?` :). Anyway this is not the way Ruby works. Actionscript has got its `with` method wich allows to work, you know, "in context" of its object. And you can't do this kind of job in Ruby.

Comment: Sure, but this is the way I see most often to achieve more or less the same. Besides `with` should be fairly easy to implement too :-)

Comment: I believe almost everything can be implemented with eval ;)

Comment: Also without `eval` it's really trivial: https://gist.github.com/2146609 Of course having to use the `self` receiver is a bit ugly, but I don't have time to hack around that at the moment.

Comment: Funny, I just saw something similar is implemented in Facets, but without returning the object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in Ruby this way. You should specify reciever

```
tester = Person.new
tester.name = "Andy"
tester.example = "Example"
```

**PS**

Here is related topic:

> [In Ruby, is there a way to accomplish what `with` does in Actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654031/in-ruby-is-there-a-way-to-accomplish-what-with-does-in-actionscript)

Comment: Well, there's something similar to what OP wants, with the `yield self` idiom that gemspec files or Rake uses. See my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

It may be set like this:

```
tester = Person.new.tap do |person|
person.name = 'John'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to call a method whose name ends in `=` without a receiver, because [doing so will create a new local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5367292/512904). I suggest allowing new values to be passed to your reader methods:

```
class Person
  def initialize(&block)
    if block.arity.zero? then instance_eval &block
    else block.call self end
  end

  def name(new_name = nil)
    @name = new_name unless new_name.nil?
    @name
  end
end
```

Now you can write:

```
Person.new do
  name 'Andy'
end
```

The only drawback to this approach is that it is impossible to set the attribute back to `nil`, so consider providing a conventional writer method as well.

Answer (score 0):

`do` is refers to the object yielded from an iteration, which doesn't allow you to write code as above. I'd suggest a different approach:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :example

    def assign(props = {})
        props.each{|prop, value| self.send("#{prop.to_s}=", value)}
        self
    end
end

x = Person.new
x.assign :name => "test", :example => "test_example"
=> #<Person:0x27a4760 @name="test", @example="test_example">
```

Answer (score -1):

@fl00r's suggestion is right or you may do it this way which is most similar to him:

```
tester = Person.new
tester[:name] = "Andy"
tester[:example] = "Example"
```

Comment: -1, this isn't even valid Ruby. Unless the `Person` class specifies a `[]=` method, you'll get a `NoMethodError`.